# Does an involution of a scheme induce an involution of the structure sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $\sigma : X \rightarrow X$ be an involution of $X$ (so $\sigma^2 = id$). I can always get an induced involution on the structure sheaf of the affinization of $X$ by noting that $LR(\mathcal O_X) = LR(\sigma_* \mathcal O_X)$, where $R$ is global sections and $L$ is the associated sheaf functor. However, if I want to turn this into an involution of $\mathcal O_X$, I need to conjugate by the counit $\epsilon : LR \rightarrow id$ of the adjunction, which is not an natural isomorphism unless $X$ is affine.

I think a potential counterexample is $\mathbb P^1$ with involution defined by $[x:y] \mapsto [y:x]$, in which case the problem is that there's not an open cover of affines which are invariant under the involution. It seems like one would want to send $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ on each of the affine covers, which is impossible.

However, even if there is such an invariant cover, I was struggling to glue some locally defined maps -- how would one show that $\epsilon_{\mathcal O_{U_i}} LR(\sigma^\# |_{U_i})\epsilon_{\mathcal O_{U_i}}^{-1}  $ and $\epsilon_{\mathcal O_{U_j}} LR(\sigma^\# |_{U_j})\epsilon_{\mathcal O_{U_j}}^{-1}  $ restrict to the same map on $U_{ij}$?

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, let me only ask for an additive involution on the sheaf.

Comment: I don't follow how you're getting an involution on the structure sheaf when $X$ is affine.  An involution in what category?  Explicitly, if $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ and $\sigma$ is the involution corresponding to $x\mapsto -x$, what is the involution of the structure sheaf you get?

Comment: @Eric An involution in the category of qcoh $\mathcal O_X$-modules. If $X = \mathrm{Spec}\ k[x]$, I get the map on $\mathcal O_{\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x]} \rightarrow \mathcal O_{\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x]}$ induced by the module map $k[x] \rightarrow k[x], x \mapsto -x$ under the equivalence of categories between $k[x]$-modules and qcoh $\mathcal O_{\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x]}$-modules.

Comment: I don't think that can possibly be right.  Note that the module map $k[x]\to k[x]$ which sends $x$ to $-x$ is just multiplication by $-1$, which is NOT the same as the _ring_ map $k[x]\to k[x]$ which sends $x$ to $-x$.

Comment: I'm confused -- the ring map is already a module map, right?: Let $X = \mathrm{Spec}\ k[x]$. A ring map $f$ induces a map of schemes, which in particular will give me a map of sheaves from $\mathcal O_X \rightarrow f_*(\mathcal O_X)$. These sheaves have the same global sections, namely $k[x]$. Now take the associated sheaf functor applied to the map on global sections.

Comment: The map on global sections is not a $k[x]$-module homomorphism!  The ring map $k[x]\to k[x]$ sending $x$ to $-x$ is not $k[x]$-linear.

Comment: (Note, in particular, that the standard $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structure on $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is the one induced by the map of sheaves of rings $\mathcal{O}_X\to f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$.  In this case, that module structure structure is NOT the same as the module structure you get by identifying $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ with $\mathcal{O}_X$ via their global sections.  In the first module structure, $x$ acts on $k[x]$ by multiplication by $-x$ instead of by multiplication by $x$.)

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly true. If I change it to just being an additive map, is there hope?

Comment: Well, the problem is that additive maps between $k[x]$-modules don't induce additive morphisms between the corresponding sheaves.  You need $k[x]$-linearity to get any map of sheaves in the first place (since you need some kind of compatibility with localization to define a map of sheaves).

Comment: Gotcha, I was hoping to extend something defined on the category of rings with involution to the category of schemes with involution, but it seems like it will be more problematic than anticipated. If you want to make your comments into an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An involution of a scheme does not naturally induce any sort of involution of its structure sheaf, even in the affine case.  Your idea is essentially that when $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, $\sigma$ induces an involution of $A$ which then corresponds to an involution of $\mathcal{O}_X$.  But this is incorrect, because the involution of $A$ is an involution of *rings*, not an involution of $A$-modules.  To get a corresponding homomorphism of sheaves, you would need a homomorphism of $A$-modules.

Geometrically, this should not be surprising.  An involution of $X$ can *move points of $X$*, whereas an involution of $\mathcal{O}_X$ has to be a sheaf morphism and so must keep every point of $X$ fixed in some sense.  Concretely, an involution of $\mathcal{O}_X$ as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module is given by multiplication by some $f\in A$ such that $f^2=1$.  It would be very weird to naturally be able to obtain such an $f$ from an involution of $A$ as a ring.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that your comments tell us how to get an additive involution on affine schemes: view $f_*(\mathcal O_X)$ as an $\mathcal O_X$-module via $f$. Then the induced map on global sections $f^{\#}$ will give a map of $\Gamma(\mathcal O_X)$-modules .Now you can use the adjunctions above to get an additive involution of $\mathcal O_X$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the map you get by doing that is just the identity map.